# Include HTML inside of component - svelte

Tags: javascript, typescript, svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component

One thing that I've been curious how to do in Svelte is include a components' HTML children in a place using svelte, like this:

```
<Popup>
  <h1>Hello World</h1>
</Popup>
```

I've done some research, and I saw that rich harris was doing this with his svelte cubed framework.[image: svelte cubed example]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to learn more about the [slot](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-slot).

*App.svelte*

```
<script>
  import Popup from './lib/Popup.svelte';
</script>

<Popup>
  <h1>Hello World</h1>
</Popup>
```

*Popup.svelte*

```
<div>
  <slot>
    This is fallback content when no content is provided
  </slot>
</div>
```